# using IIS instead of IIS Express on visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, webserver

I have been trying to run my webapp in visual studio with IIS instead of IIS express, i went into add windows features and enabled IIS, this enabled a extra dropdown box inside visual studi called local IIS.  but i get this error[image]

so my question is, do i have to start it externally like i would a wamp server. through IIS manager, or can i do it through visual studio?  and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Try to run the visual studio as administrator.

Comment: it is currently in administrator mode, sadly

Comment: So, maybe you can do this manually in your local IIS. To do this, add a new app in your default web site and point the fisical path to your folder.